# Unable to run keycloak in https

Tags: ssl, keycloak

I am trying to run keycloak on HTTPS using a self-signed certificate.
I followed this doc https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_installation/topics/network/https.html.
I have done everything as mentioned but skipped the CA certificate request because I need self-signed.
But it is still running in HTTP and not HTTPS .
It would be great if anyone would be able to guide me in this.

I have created the certificate with the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keystore keycloak.jks -validity 10950
```

I have made the following changes in standalone.xml:

```
<security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
    <server-identities>
    <ssl>
        <keystore path="keycloak.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" alias="localhost" keystore-password="my_passward" />
    </ssl>
    </server-identities>
</security-realm>
```

and changed the HTTPS listener part to the new security realm :

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
```

What am I missing? why is it not running in HTTPS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new security realm element using CLI tools.
Do refer to this [official documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_installation/#enabling-ssl-https-for-the-keycloak-server) for more.